# I want to make something but i have to bend light without a black hole

Tags: particle-physics

I am trying to make something that requires a vortex of light, but the only thing i know that can do that is a black hole . . . so is there any possibility that i can make the vortex without a black hole?

Comment: What is a "vortex of light?" Vortices are phenomena of fluids.

Comment: And how do you make a light vortex *with* a black hole?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to build, but you can redirect light using fiber optic cable.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear, but for what I know a [**vortex of light**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_vortex) can be a laser beam carrying a phase singularity on its axis. This gives a phase profile (measurable by interference) which is helical, or a vortex:

[image: an optical vortex. left: intensity, right:phase]

*(Fig: an optical vortex. left: intensity, right:phase)*

There are several ways to [**produce**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_vortex#Creation) it, e.g. using computer generated holograms on a spatial light modulator.